# Assign a filename to uploaded data

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm using:

```
            $result = $analytics->management_uploads->uploadData(self::$accountId, self::$webPropertyId, $dataSourceId, array(
                    "data"          => $dataCsv,
                    "mimeType"      => 'application/octet-stream',
                    "uploadType"    => 'media')
        );
```

where $dataCsv is content csv file.

How do I assign a filename?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like assigning a filename is not supported in the Google API. However if you want to manage your uploads through API, you could store (or list) the id that your upload was being assigned. For example:

```
/**
 * Upload data to Google Analytics property in dataset
 *
 * @param string $accountId
 * @param string $webPropertyId
 * @param string $customDataSourceId
 * @param string $uploadCSV
 *
 * @return integer upload ID
 */
public function upload($accountId, $webPropertyId, $customDataSourceId, $uploadCSV, $prev_upload_id = null) {
    $result = $this->getAnalyticsService()->management_uploads->uploadData(
        $accountId,
        $webPropertyId,
        $customDataSourceId,
        [
            'data'       => $uploadCSV,
            'mimeType'   => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'media'
        ] );

    $this->last_upload_status = $result['status'];

    return $result['id'];
}
```

With the id you can for example delete a previous upload like:

```
/**
 * Upload data to Google Analytics property in dataset
 *
 * @param string $accountId
 * @param string $webPropertyId
 * @param string $customDataSourceId
 * @param integer $prev_upload_id
 */
public function deleteUpload($accountId, $webPropertyId, $customDataSourceId, $prev_upload_id)
{
    if (!is_null($prev_upload_id)) {
        $body = new \Google_Service_Analytics_AnalyticsDataimportDeleteUploadDataRequest();
        $body->setCustomDataImportUids([$prev_upload_id]);
        $uploads = $this->getAnalyticsService()->management_uploads->deleteUploadData(
            $accountId,
            $webPropertyId,
            $customDataSourceId,
            $body
        );
    }
}
```